# How to upgrade the pricing tier of notifcation hub instance from free tier to basic tier

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-notificationhub

I am looking to upgrade the pricing tier of notification hub instance from free tier to basic tier.

Is it possible to upgrade it using powershell script so that I will not have any downtime for the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your tier using the [Set-AzureRmNotificationHubsNamespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.notificationhubs/set-azurermnotificationhubsnamespace?view=azurermps-4.3.1) PowerShell command where `$skuTier` can `free`, `basic` or `standard`:

```
Set-AzureRmNotificationHubsNamespace 
     -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup 
     -Namespace $namespaceName 
     -Location $location 
     -Tags $tags 
     -skuTier $skuTier
```